# Change integer to bigint key in a table without long exclusive lock

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is it possible to inherit a table with column of type `int` from a table with the same column of type `bigint` in PostgreSQL 9.1?

Changing the column type to `bigint` if the first table is not an option.

I have a table with several tens of millions entries that has an ID of int. Right now that ID is slowly approaching to 2^32, and I was thinking if it's a reasonable thing to create a facade table with bigint ID and let the original one inherit the facade. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change the type of a column of the parent table when you inherit from the table.

The column type must match, since when you query the parent table (without an `ONLY` in your `FROM` clause) PostgreSQL implicitly scans the child tables too and appends their results. It can't do that if the types differ, much the same way you can't `UNION` tables of different types.

**Update based on comments**:

### Use a view and a `DO INSTEAD` trigger

I suggest using a view that's a union of the two tables, with the old table's contents upcast to `bigint`. Define an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that redirects `INSERT`s to the new table.

If you do `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s you should probably define a `CHECK` constraint on each table that restricts the range of IDs to a non-overlapping range, then decide which table to route the `DELETE` or `UPDATE` to based on the ID.

For `UPDATE`s you could even transform it into a `DELETE ... RETURNING` and an `INSERT` (possibly in a wCTE) to move the row from the old table to the new one as part of the update.

You *will* incur a performance penalty for this, but you'll avoid the need for a full table rewrite.

### Progressively change the key type in-place

You say that changing the key type isn't an option, but really what you seem to mean is "changing the key type in a manner that requires a full table rewrite under an exclusive lock is not an option".

What you *can* do is:

- `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN new_key bigint;` . Do *not* mark it `NOT NULL` or give it a `DEFAULT`
- Add a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ... BEFORE EACH ROW ...` trigger to the table that copies the integer ID column to the bigint id column, e.g. `NEW.new_id := NEW.id`
- In batches, `UPDATE` the table to copy the integer key to the bigint column, and `VACUUM` after each batch
- Once all new and existing rows have a bigint key, create a unique index on it using `create unique index ... concurrently`.
- Once the index is created, add a `not null` constraint. Unfortunately this will do a sequential scan to validate the constraint. If you can't tolerate even that, there are hacks to work around it, but I'm not prepared to advise them in public because you need to know *exactly* what you're doing to do it safely, and use it in the right circumstances.
- `begin` a transaction, `drop` the trigger, `drop` the old primary key constraint and the old `id` column, and add a new primary key constraint on the bigint key, specifying the existing index you created concurrently as the constraint index, then `commit`. This avoids the need to build the index under an exclusive lock.

This process would be better if PostgreSQL supported adding a `not null` constraint as `not valid`, then let you validate it with a weaker lock. It doesn't yet do so, unfortunately. Patches or other contributions are welcome.

You would benefit significantly from the weaker locks taken by `alter table` for some operations on PostgreSQL 9.5.

Theoretically PostgreSQL could support `alter table ... alter type ... concurrently` by doing all this behind the scenes. There'd be a *lot* of work in doing it properly though, so I don't anticipate seeing a simple and canned approach to this in the near future.

Comment: Are there any hacks available? Adding rules/constraints/conversions/whatever?

Comment: Model it with a normal foreign key relationship, not inheritance. Or change the type of the base table's column and incur the rewrite penalty. That's about it, really.

Comment: Sorry to turn this one into a chat, but just to elaborate on situation: I have a table with several tens of millions entries that has an ID of int. Right now that ID is slowly approaching to 2^32, and I was thinking if it's a reasonable thing to create a facade table with bigint ID and let the original one inherit the facade. Does it make any sense?

Comment: @AndreiPetrenko This is why you should explain what problem you're trying to solve, not just assume a particular way you think you should solve the problem and ask how to implement that solution.